# C++ Infinite-loop, Issue with returning

Tags: c++, loops, vector, infinite

```
void phonebookmenu() {
    phonebook ph;

    string str;

    cin.ignore();
    cout << "PH> ";
    getline(cin, str); //Input from user.

    string buf; // Have a buffer string.
    stringstream ss(str); // Insert the string into a stream.
    vector<string> tokens; // Create vector to hold the words.

    while (ss >> buf){
        tokens.push_back(buf); //Adds all the words inside the vector.
    }

    while (true){
    if (tokens[0] == "add"){
            ph.add(tokens[1],tokens[2]);
    }
    else if(tokens[0] == "lookup"){
            ph.lookup(tokens[1]);
    }
    else if(tokens[0] == "change"){
            ph.change(tokens[1],tokens[2]);
    }
    else if(tokens[0] == "alias"){
            ph.alias(tokens[1],tokens[2]);
    }
    else if(tokens[0] == "quit"){

            //Return to the "Main-menu"
    }

    else{
        cout << "Invalid input" << endl;
    }
}
```

So i'm calling this menu from a "Main-menu" but after i have input something like "Add peter 123" it does the function then returns to the "Main-menu" which i don't want. It's supposed to go back to

```
cout << "PH> ";
```

So i can continue to make operations.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How do i make this loop work correctly? It's only doing it ONCE then goes back to the "Main-menu".

Comment: You need to add a loop if you want it to loop.

Comment: The description of what your code's behavior does not match what the code is actually doing. You code should end up getting stuck in an infinite loop, because you have no means of breaking out of the while(true) loop,

Comment: It's supposed to go back to "cout << "PH> "; and read the input again and see if i want to lookup, add or exit (If exit THEN return to "Main-menu")

Comment: I'm really new into programming so i don't really know where to place everything.

Comment: In that case, you have to put another loop, in order to implement. Or even use goto (let the flame wars begin!)

Comment: Provide us with a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If you're really new to programming, you should try something less complicated first, until you understand how basic control flow statements work -- if, for, while, etc...

Comment: Can i upload a whole project somewhere so u can check it out?

Comment: See also: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: you might want to show the you `main`. Or whatever is calling the method you provide here... Not quite sure if it is what you mean, but if you want the method to be called repeatedly you will need a loop around the call..

Comment: I just solved it, thank you all, not much was needed ;D

Comment: Most likely pretty bad question hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop is not around the `cout/input/determine/do something` logic. It's only around the `determine/do something`. Move the `while` to before the `cout` and see what happens.
Be sure to mark the answer that helps most as an answer.